# function using cl-who:with-html-output ignoring parameter

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I'm not sure whether this is an issue with my use of `cl-who` (specifically `with-html-output-to-string` and `with-html-output`) or an issue with my understanding of Common Lisp (as this is my first project using Lisp).

I created a function to create form fields:

```
(defun form-field (type name label)
  (cl-who:with-html-output (*standard-output* nil)
    (:div :class "field"
      (:label :for name label)
      (:input :type type :name name))))
```

When using this function, ie: `(form-field "text" "username" "Username")` the parameter `label` seems to be ignored... the HTML output is:

```
<div class="field"><label for="username"></label>
<input type="text" name="username"/></div>
```

instead of the expected output:

```
<div class="field"><label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username"/></div>
```

If I modify the function and add a print statement:

```
(defun form-field (type name label)
  (cl-who:with-html-output (*standard-output* nil)
    (print label)
    (:div :class "field"
      (:label :for name label)
      (:input :type type :name name))))
```

The "Username" string is successfully output (but still ignored in the HTML)... any ideas what might cause this?

Keep in mind, I'm calling this function within a `cl-who:with-html-output-to-string` for use with hunchentoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation is described in the [CL-WHO evaluation rules](http://weitz.de/cl-who/#syntax) under "A form which is neither a string nor a keyword..." `(:label :for name label)` falls under that rule, and it's just evaluated, but it doesn't output anything so it has no effect. One easy fix: use `(str label)` instead.